# Remove XML name space where using XDocument to select a Descenant

Tags: c#, xml

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
   <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
   <Header>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/charities/r68/2">
      </IRenvelope>
   </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

I am selecting just the Body element with the following code (XmlDocument is the xml file Parsed as an XDocument)

```
var xmlBody = XmlDocument.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name.LocalName == "Body");
```

When i view the xmlBody it has added the parent namespace

```
<Body xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
     <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/charities/r68/2">
     </IRenvelope>
 </Body>
```

I convert the xmlBody from an XElement to a XmlNode and thenHash the body for another process so therefore need to remove the namespace from the body element.
How can i remove the namespace or prevent it from being added?

Comment: If I take a wild guess and assume you're going to generate an `IRMark` from this, you very much need to leave it as it is - see 1.1 in [these docs](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/366490/irmark_step_by_step_govtalk.pdf).

Comment: @CharlesMager - You are correct! Thanks for your help - I did indeed need to keep the name space in the body